# Open Accordion first tab

Tags: accordion

I have an accordion in a ul > li > ul > li list.
It has three boxes that are closed on page load, but I wish to have the first box open on page load. The following is all the jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(e){
    if($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
      // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
      $("#nav li ul").slideUp(350);
      $("#nav li a").removeClass("open");

      // open our new menu and add the open class
      $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
      $(this).addClass("open");
    }

    else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $(this).removeClass("open");
      $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
    }
  });
});
```

The html is a simple ul > li > ul > li list.

Comment: Nevermind, I did it. I put a '.first' class and a display:block on the first ul > li > ul.first.

Answer (score 0):

If your menu has only links and sub-links (NO header), put this in the css:

```
ul#nav li:first-child ul {
  display:block;
}
```